# When configuring a binary tree, is it possible to just increase the height to a null node?

Tags: binary-tree

For example, can such a binary tree exist?

```
     A        
   /   \      
  N     N     
 / \   / \  
N   B C   N
```

It's just a question out of my curiosity.

Comment: Yes. Why not? It is possible.

Comment: -– Some programmer dude 
It's just a question out of my curiosity.

Comment: -– Some programmer dude thx for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this tree can exist. The main rule of binary tree is it can have maximum of two children.

However, there is `Binary search tree`. BST is a binary tree, but it has more conditions:

- All the keys (data inside the node) are unique/distinct.
- Every left child key value of every parent node,  is smaller than the parent node key value.
- Every right child key value of every parent node, is larger than the parent node key value.